# how to increase the performance of the java application fetching a large data from oracle database?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, oracle

I have 3 database tables - Items, Audits and Comments. I have to fetch a large amount of data from *Items* table, say 1 million records, and for each item fetched, I have to retrive the data from *Audits* and *Comments* and write the report to a delimited file. So the output may look like ,

```
Item entry 1
    Audit entry 1 for Item 1
    Audit entry 2 for Item 1
    Audit entry 3 for Item 1
    Comment entry 1 for Item 1
    Comment entry 2 for Item 1
Item entry 2 
    Audit entry 1 for Item 2
    .
    .
    .
```

Now this is taking so much time, because the program is querying the oracle 1 million times for every *item*. I would like to increase the performance thru threads but i'm not familiar with the threads. So could someone help me with the performance increase ?

Comment: Please include the algorithm and queries your are currently using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a stored procedure that would output the file with utl_file package and just call that from java. That way you can just use something like

```
f := utl_file.fopen('my_dir','my_file','w');
FOR r_items IN (SELECT * FROM items) LOOP
  utl_file.put_line(f,r_items.name);

  FOR r_audit IN (SELECT * FROM audit WHERE item_id = r_items.id) LOOP
    utl_file.put_line(f,r_audit.some_field);
  END LOOP;

  FOR r_comments IN (SELECT * FROM comments WHERE item_id = r_items.id) LOOP
    utl_file.put_line(f,r_comments.some_field);
  END LOOP;
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve the Items, a joined query to obtain the Audit and another to obtain the Comments.

A way to speed up the query results is to return the select line as a single concatenated string and split the line yourself.  This used to speed up retrieval by a factor of 2-3.  Newer versions of Oracle may be smarter in this regard and have less overhead.

However the volume of data you have this is likely to take a while to get from Oracle in any case.

Comment: Peter, cool man... Concat is a great idea.. that will speed up for sure. I'll use this one and tell you the increase factor.

Answer (score 2):

Read this resource: http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join.asp and use join.

Comment: No. I cannot use joins. As you can see i need to give the output in 3 different types of rows. First row should contain the record from _item_ table and the next set of rows from _audit_ and _comment_ tables

Comment: To get the join to work, you do perform three queries. (rather than doing everything in a single join) You can perform a query on the audit table obtaining ALL the records which match the keys for the item table, and then perform the matching in memory.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you are doing, and what your real problem is from the limited information you have provided.

- If you are doing a million individual (small) queries, you should consider restructuring your application so that it combines them in batches, or does a SELECT over the entire table.
- If the problem is fetching a million rows in a single query, then consider using a more complicated query, or a stored query, or something to do some data reduction on the database side.

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to combine a UNION with a JOIN to fetch all data the best way.
The query might look something like this:

```
select itm.itemid
,      tmp.what || ' ' || tmp.entry || ' for Item ' || tmp.itemid line
from   items itm
join
(
    select itemid
    ,      entry 
    ,      'Audit' what
    from   audits
    union all
    select itemid
    ,      entry 
    ,      'Comment' what
    from   comments
) tmp on itm.itemid = tmp.itemid
```

Answer (score 0):

My thought is run three queries (one to return all the items, one for all the comments and one for all the audit entries) each one sorted by item id

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT itemid, 1 type, null seq, item_line line
   from items
   union all
   select itemid, 2, audit_seq, audit_line
   from audit
   union all
   select itemid, 3, comment_seq comment_line 
   from comments)
order by itemid, type, seq
```

It means putting all the logic to build the line entries into the database but it will probably run a lot faster than the java code.

Answer (score 0):

After you manage your UNION/JOIN as BazzPsychoNut said, it may be helpful to adjust the FetchSize value to greater value if the ResultSet is big. The default value for Oracle is 10.

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.setFetchSize(200);
ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your system (hardware, configuration etc) is sized to handle the amount of data you put in it, the best, fastest and simplest way is to simply join the tables in one query, fetch the rows (see other comments about fetch_size) and then dump it in whatever format you want.

Judging from the example output format, you need to process the rows in sorted order (item, audit, comments). You would iterate over the rows and keeping track of the last item processed, and whenever the current ITEM_ID is different from the previous you output the item data.

The single most important aspect for you to consider when you decide on how to implement this, is whether the join and sort fits in memory or not. If the sort/join spills to disk, you will have to work around that in order to achieve the desired performance. Some examples on how to avoid the disk spill:

Hash partition the tables (or a copy of them) on the ITEM_ID. You may then join the tables partitionwise so that each join fits inside memory.

Or you could fetch all data from all tables, and in your java code, put the items in a linked list, and the audits/comments in some hash-based structure keyed by item_no. You'd then iterate over the items and query audit/comments by the item_id. This solution avoids a sort operation, and doesn't need to fit the joined result in memory.

Or you can implement some do-it-yourself partitioning. For example, query the data 9 times. In the first query you fetch only items with ITEM_ID starting or ending with 1. Second query fetcehs all items starting/ending with 2 etcetera. This solution results in 9 table scans on all tables, which is clearly not very efficient. But if you can avoid the spill to disk, it may actually be faster.